# Как правильно использовать toFixed()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не являюсь специалистом в JavaScript, но пришлось сделать калькулятор расчета стоимости на сайте:

```js
$(document).ready(function() { // Ждём загрузки страницы
  $("input[name=send]").click(function() { // Событие нажатия на кнопку "Расчёт"
    var mileage = $("input[name=mileage]").val() * 1; // Переменная пробега
    var rate = $("input[name=rate]").val() * 1; // Переменная расхода
    var volume = mileage * rate * 365 / 100; // Переменная объема топлива за год
    var price = $("input[name=price]:checked").val(); // Переменная цены
    var result = volume * price; // Переменная результата
    $("input[name=result]").val(result); // записываем результат
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>2. Выберите марку бензина</h4>
<label for="92">92</label>
<input type="radio" name="price" value="42" class="price" id="92">
<label for="95">95</label>
<input type="radio" name="price" value="45" class="price" id="95">
<label for="98">98</label>
<input type="radio" name="price" value="48" class="price" id="98">
<h4>3. Сколько км. вы проезжаете за день?</h4>
<label for="myRange"></label>
<input type="range" name="mileage" min="1" max="500" value="50" step="1" class="slider" id="myRange">
<p>Км: <span id="demo"></span></p>
<h4>4. Укажите расход в км. на 100 литров</h4>
<label for="myRange2"></label>
<input type="range" name="rate" min="1" max="100" value="13" step="1" class="slider" id="myRange2">
<p>Л: <span id="demo2"></span></p>
</div>
<input type="button" id="r" name="send" value="Рассчитать" />
<label for="r">Результат:</label>
<input type="text" id="" name="result" placeholder="Ответ" />
```

Так как переменная `volume` часто содержит знаки после запятой, необходимо округлить переменную `result`, но в каком месте я бы не использовал `toFixed()` - результат не меняется. Все остальные переменные являются целыми числами, так как они заполняются из `input` и проходят валидацию полей.

Возможно, это имеет значение: сайт поднят на basic шаблоне yii2, в Assets подключен jquery-3.5.1.js. А вот при запуске этого скрипта в независимом от проекта файле *.html округление методом Math.round() работает, как часы.

Comment: Добавьте свой html

Answer (score 0):

Метод Math.round() - округляет до ближайшего целого, например этот код вернёт 15

```
const num = 15.3
Math.round(num)
```

Comment: var result = Math.round(volume*price); Сделал так, не помогает

Comment: В вашем html нет начальных значений, установите checked в любом checkbox

Answer (score 0):

[toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

```js
$(document).ready(function() { // Ждём загрузки страницы
  $("input[name=send]").click(function() { // Событие нажатия на кнопку "Расчёт"
    var mileage = +$("input[name=mileage]").val(); // Переменная пробега        
    var rate = +$("input[name=rate]").val(); // Переменная расхода
    var volume = mileage * rate * 365 / 100; // Переменная объема топлива за год
    var price = +$("input[name=price]:checked").val(); // Переменная цены
    var result = volume * price; // Переменная результата

    $("input[name=result]").val(result.toFixed(2)); // записываем результат
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>2. Выберите марку бензина</h4>
<label for="92">92</label>
<input type="radio" name="price" value="42" class="price" id="92" checked>
<label for="95">95</label>
<input type="radio" name="price" value="45" class="price" id="95">
<label for="98">98</label>
<input type="radio" name="price" value="48" class="price" id="98">
<h4>3. Сколько км. вы проезжаете за день?</h4>
<label for="myRange"></label>
<input type="range" name="mileage" min="1" max="500" value="50" step="1" class="slider" id="myRange">
<p>Км: <span id="demo"></span></p>
<h4>4. Укажите расход в км. на 100 литров</h4>
<label for="myRange2"></label>
<input type="range" name="rate" min="1" max="100" value="13" step="1" class="slider" id="myRange2">
<p>Л: <span id="demo2"></span></p>
</div>
<input type="button" id="r" name="send" value="Рассчитать" />
<label for="r">Результат:</label>
<input type="text" id="" name="result" placeholder="Ответ" />
```

Ну и вместо `* 1` для приведения к числу можно ипользовать `+`

Comment: К сожалению, нет. В отдельном html документе код отрабатывает и без параметра checked. А в проекте поднятом на yii2 не срабатывает. Причем не срабатывает избирательно, то есть toFixed(2) или console.log(result) не работают. Но сам подсчет работает и формула считает всё верно.

Answer (score 0):

Всем, кто помогал спасибо за помощь! Если бы не танцы с бубном после ваших советов так бы и бросил. Проблема решилась очень странно - после перезагрузки компа в конце рабочего дня. Очень стыдно за то, что навел шороху из ничего. Судя по всему при подключении новых файлов *.js через AppAssets в проекте yii2 они не сразу подгружают библиотеки jQuery, поэтому половина кода из скрипта работала, а половина нет. Подключаемые файлы без jQuery без проблем отрабатывают, а также при вынесении кода в теги  внутри html документа - jQuery работает нормально. Вердикт - при связке Windows 10, OpenServer, phpstorm и yii2 проблемы с подключением библиотек при отсутствии внешних признаков можно проверять перезагрузкой системы.